# Shell scripts for Meld Nautilus context menu

Tags: linux, shell, nautilus, meld

[Beyond Compare](http://www.scootersoftware.com/moreinfo.php) provides "Select for compare" and "Compare to Selected" by using two nautilus scripts (stored in `/home/user/.gnome2/nautilus-scripts`).

Script 1: Select for compare

```
#!/bin/sh
quoted=$(echo "$NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS" | awk 'BEGIN { FS = "\n" } { printf "\"%s\" ", $1 }' | sed -e s#\"\"##)
echo "$quoted" > $HOME/.beyondcompare/nautilus
```

Script 2: Compare to Selected

```
#!/bin/sh
arg2=$(cat $HOME/.beyondcompare/nautilus)
arg1=$(echo "$NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS" | awk 'BEGIN { FS = "\n" } { printf "\"%s\" ", $1 }' | sed -e s#\"\"##)
bcompare $arg1 $arg2
```

I am trying to do similar scripts for [Meld](http://meld.sourceforge.net/), but it is not working.

I am not familiar with shell scripts. Can anyone help me understand this:

```
quoted=$(echo "$NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS" | awk 'BEGIN { FS = "\n" } { printf "\"%s\" ", $1 }' | sed -e s#\"\"##)
```

so that I can adapt to meld.

Comment: If it is not imperative to use shel script, you can use this: http://my.opera.com/bachkhois/blog/2011/07/19/compare-files-with-meld-from-within-nautilus
It is a Nautilus plugin written in Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quoted=$( ...) assigns whatever output there is to the variable named quoted, and can be used later in the script as $quoted OR ${quoted} OR "${quoted}" OR "$quoted"

The '|' char is called a 'pipe' in unix/linux and it connects the output of the preceding command to feed into the following command.

So you just take the script apart 1 piece at a time and see what it does,

```
quoted=$(
# I would execute below by itself first
echo "$NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS"
# then add on this piped program to see how data gets transformed
| awk 'BEGIN { FS = "\n" } { printf "\"%s\" ", $1 }' 
# then add this
| sed -e s#\"\"##
# the capturing of the output to the var 'quoted' is the final step of code
)

# you **cannot** copy paste this whole block of code and expect it to work ;-)
```

I don't know what is supposed to be in $NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS, so it is hard to show you here. AND, that variable is not defined in any of the code you specify here, so you may only get a blank line when you `echo` its value. Be prepared to do some research on how that value get set AND what are the correct values.

Also I notice that your code is 'prefixed' as `#!/bin/sh`. If it is truly /bin/sh then command substitution like `quoted=$(....)` will not work and should generate an error message. Persumably your system is really using bash for /bin/sh. You can eliminate any possible confusion in the future (when changing to a system where /bin/sh = bourne shell), by changing the 'shebang' to `#! /bin/bash`.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

If you are not rolling your own solution for the sake of learning, I would suggest installing the `diff-ext` extension to nautilus. It is cross platform and if you are running Debian/Ubuntu installing it should be as simple as `sudo apt-get install diff-ext`.

Check out some screenshots here - http://diff-ext.sourceforge.net/screenshots.shtml

Comment: At least for ubuntu bionic beaver (18.04), ```diff-ext``` is not available. ```sudo apt-get install meld nautilus-compare``` was suitable for me. Note that you need to close all nautilus windows (```nautilus -q```) and restart before you can see the file context menu.

Answer (score 0):

I just discovered diff-ext thanks to this post, excellent!

The first try I did failed: by default diff-ext does not handle backup files (*~ and *.bak). To enable this, run:

```
$ diff-ext-setup
```

and in the `Mime types` pane, check `application/x-trash`.

Now you can compare a file and its backup.